# Find which row is clicked in the List View

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

I have a listview with 2 possible layouts for each row.

When implementing my onClick listener for each row, I'm trying to find the most efficient way to figure out which type of row was clicked so I can obtain data from it.

Is there a more efficient way than this? I wanted to access the `getItemViewType(position)` function but I couldnt successfully access it from `parent`:

```
// listening to single list item on click
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // selected item's TextView
        // if the first view is null, it must be the other kind
        TextView tView = null;
        if(view.getId() == R.list.layout_a) tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.list.text_a);
          else tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.list.text_b);

        //DO STUFF AND LAUNCH ACTIVITY
    }
});
```

Layouts - This is an overly simplified example, but I need to know if the row that was clicked uses `R.list.text_a` or `R.list.text_b`. Can I give the root LinearLayout an `android:id=` attribute?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+list/layout_a"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip" 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/text_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+list/layout_b"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip" 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/text_b"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by more efficient. Its as efficient as its gonna get lol. You click a row, and you get that rows stuff. What do you mean by figure out which type of row?

Comment: Finding view by Id is a relatively expensive call. I would think that if you had different textviews at different positions, you could just refer to the position in your data container to find the type of view you have. Perhaps even have an array just to hold the type of view at that position. But since you launch a new activity after this, I assume that this won't be clicked often so the costs might not be felt.

Comment: @Mango - Updated my code above... Can I add an `android:id=` attribute to the LinearLayouts above? Will that value be returned in the adapter by calling `view.getId()` ?

Comment: while that is a fine method, this was never my intention. In the `getView()` of your adapter, surely you have some sort of condition for what makes a textview go where. whether it's at odd or even positions or something. i meant use the `View view, **int position**, long id` parameter to compare with that. or just make an array that contains these conditions in some form. of course, ultimately it's up to you how you wanna do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have ids on each of the layouts that are within each position that differ. If you don't ignore this. If you do however you could just compare the views id with one of the ids that you know and determine which type of layout it is. Should be a pretty cheap call.

I believe you should be able to give it an ID.

Comment: See updated example above. I have given each layout an id attribute at the root level (like `android:id="@+list/layout_a"`), which is the ID that is returned by `view.getId()` in the adapter.

Comment: If you have added it in is there any issue in using getid()? I would have thought it should work fine.

Comment: I'll award you the answer because that's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks also to @yahya

Answer (score 1):

In your xml, set your views' tag:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+list/layout_a"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip" 
android:tag="a"    // Here is important part!

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/text_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+list/layout_b"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip" 
android:tag="b"    // Here is important part!

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/text_b"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your code:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if(view.getTag().toString().equals("a")) {
          // Do whatever you need to do with layout a
    } else if(view.getTag().toString().equals("b")) {
          // Do whatever you need to do with layout b
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Using view.getId() got me to the same place :) `if(view.getId() == R.list.layout_a)`